# React router pressing back in the browser changes props

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So as in the title, I have 2 routes one main one 'Home' and then when one of the links from Home component is pressed it goes to '/m/milestoneID/p/projectID', whenever I go to the second route and press back in the browser I get an error, it seems like the data I'm passing to Home component with .reverse() is no longer reversed after backing.

```
const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/m/:milestoneID/p/:projectID" component={ProjectDetails} />
        <Route component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
);
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ChronologyGraph
        width="1000"
        height="2000"
        nodeSize={10}
        milestones={milestones.reverse()}
        columns={nodeTypes}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: where milestones is passed from? is it a props?

Comment: @AntonioPangallo Yep props

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide the history in the Router:

```
import { Router } from 'react-router'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

const history = createBrowserHistory()

<Router history={history}>
```

Comment: I have tried this, the same error occurs https://imgur.com/a/KtpHnju this issue occurs because the data in props in 'unreversed' for some reason after pressing back

Comment: Have you used withRouter? You also need to use withRouter to get history props.

Comment: I have not, I will try it now, though I was wondering why are the props getting messed up? This seems like a bit of an overkill for such a simple site